# How to copy email address in outlook 2007

Tags: email, outlook, outlook-2007, email-address

I use MS Office Outlook 2007, and sometimes it converts email address as "FirstName LastName". When double click, it opens Contact form, but nowhere email address to copy into clipboard.

How is it possible to copy to clipboard email address if it uses contact?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

I had the same question.  You can right click on the user entry and select "Send Mail" to open a new email to the user with the email address in the To field instead of the "Firstname Lastname" format.  Copy the email address to the clipboard and close the new email window.

Comment: This works, but due to some MS idiocy the address turns into the descriptor as soon as the window loses focus, so you have to repeat the steps each time.

Answer (score 8):

If you need to copy several addresses, you can find them in the raw internet headers:

1. Go to the Inbox or folder that contains the message.
2. Right-click on the message with the addresses.
3. Select "Message Options"
4. Scroll down in the "Internet Headers" box until you find the addresses.
5. Highlight and copy the desired address(es).

This method has the advantage that the Message Options window will remain open until you click the 'Close' button.

Answer (score 3):

If you start a new mail, and enter their name in the usual manner, you can right-click and do "Add Contact". That opens a page where their email address is listed as copyable text. Hightlight and copy the address, close the window, and tell it not to save any changes.

Comment: This answer is actually the easiest. And if you save changes, it will even be easier to copy address / email that person in the future.

Answer (score 1):

This is a long work around I found, but is only beneficial if you have huge list and you want only the email addresses separated from the names because it has several steps. First click on the email that you want to copy the addresses from.  Select all the email addresses you want and then copy them.  Select your contacts folder and create a new contact group.  Select add members and add the members from the address book.  When the address book pops up paste the names that you copied from the email address.  Select OK.  Now that you have your new contact groups, on the file tab save as rich text format.  Once you have saved it as rich text format, copy and paste the names and email addresses from the rich text page.  Take that information you just copied from the rich text format page and paste it into an Excel spreadsheet.  Here you see that the names and email addresses have been separated.